# Loading ElasticSearch data into R

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am trying to load elasticsearch(through elasticstash) data onto R for the first time. I am running into an error as is shown in the screenshot below. What can I do to get the data into R?

Some code that I've tried:

[image]

Error message:

[image: error message]

Comment: `elastic` maintainer here. See the docs on getting started https://docs.ropensci.org/elastic/articles/elastic.html you need to create an object with `connect()` and pass that to the various `elastic` methods

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i will look into it.